# Custom post type category name wordpress

Tags: wordpress, post, categories

I've got in my Wordpress a custom post_type, with categories. How to display the category name in the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
the_category();
```

Or if you want to list the categories for a post, comma deliminated:

```
the_category(', ');
```

codex is your friend - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_category

Comment: What is happening? Is there any output at all? Or just blank space where you expect an output?

Comment: Yeah, blank space. But I found a solution: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms. That's working ;)

Comment: Good good. That's strange that `the_category()` didn't work, but glad I could help in some way! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
//Returns All Term Items for "my_taxonomy"
$term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'my_taxonomy', array("fields" => "all"));
print_r($term_list);
Array
(
    [0] => WP_Term Object
        (
        [term_id] => 145
        [name] => Example Category
        [slug] => example-cat
        [term_group] => 0
        [term_taxonomy_id] => 145
        [taxonomy] => adcpt_categories
        [description] => 
        [parent] => 0
        [count] => 2
        [filter] => raw
    )

)
```